# How to send confirmation email at the time of customer creation programatically?

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account, magento2.3

How to send confirmation email at the time of customer creation programatically ?

Customer created,but I cannot send confirmation email? Any help?

```
 public function createCustomerSocial($data, $store)
{
    /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
    $customer = $this->customerDataFactory->create();
    $customer->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
        ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
        ->setEmail($data['email'])
        ->setStoreId($store->getId())
        ->setWebsiteId($store->getWebsiteId())
        ->setCreatedIn($store->getName());

    try {
        // If customer exists existing hash will be used by Repository
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

        $objectManager     = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $mathRandom        = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Math\Random');
        $newPasswordToken  = $mathRandom->getUniqueHash();
        $accountManagement = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');
        $accountManagement->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($customer, $newPasswordToken);
        $subscriber= $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory');
        $subscriber->create()->subscribe($data['email']);

//            if ($this->apiHelper->canSendPassword($store)) {
                $this->getEmailNotification()
                    ->newAccount($customer, EmailNotificationInterface::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION);
            $this->getEmailNotification()
                ->newAccount($customer, EmailNotificationInterface::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED);
//            }

            $this->setAuthorCustomer($data['identifier'], $customer->getId(), $data['type']);
        } catch (AlreadyExistsException $e) {
            throw new InputMismatchException(
                __('A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website.')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($customer->getId()) {
                $this->_registry->register('isSecureArea', true, true);
                $this->customerRepository->deleteById($customer->getId());
            }
            throw $e;
        }

        /** @var Customer $customer */
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customer->getId());

        return $customer;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this code when you creating new customer.

```
$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

Comment: $this->getEmailNotification()
                    ->newAccount($customer, EmailNotificationInterface::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION);  this is the same , not working